# Unable to load data through SQL Loader if a decimal is in last column

Tags: sql-loader

When I have the decimal field as the last value in my record, I am not able to load it into a table using SQL loader. I am doing it on LINUX OS and with Oracle 12C.

Below is the code from my .ctl file.

```
OPTIONS (SILENT=(HEADER,FEEDBACK),ERRORS=0)
LOAD DATA
TRUNCATE INTO TABLE STG_HIST_VSPT
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
col1,
col2,
col3,
STARTDATE DATE 'DD-MM-YYYY',
QTY
)
```

and below is how the data is in the file.

```
6106|#CLIENTE SIN ASIGNAR#|399_8|31-12-2012|0.022500
6254|#CLIENTE SIN ASIGNAR#|399_8|21-01-2013|0.082500
6254|#CLIENTE SIN ASIGNAR#|399_8|04-03-2013|0.180000
```

Below is the error I see in the log file.
    Record 1: Rejected - Error on table STG_HIST_VSPT, column QTY.
    ORA-01722: invalid number

Can someone let me know what's the problem here? If I create a file on my own, I am able to load it but this file which I received from another system is not allowing me to load!!

Answer (score 0):

By adding 'TERMINATED BY WHITESPACE' I was able to load the file successfully.